# How can I count every word from a table in a .txt file

Tags: python, word-count

I have a table of words and I would like to count how many times these words occur in a .txt file.

So far I have written the word I want to be counted in the file like this:

```
word = 'sustainable'
word_count = file.count(word)
print('Number of occurences of the word', word, ': ', word_count)
```

But then I would have to write every single word I want to be counted.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter would be a good use case here or make a dictionary and do it yourself

Comment: how about `x = set(<file-string>.split())` and then do a loop over `x` ?   (.split() splits a string by spaces and the use of `set` makes sure that you have only unique elements in the list `x`)